# C++ Issue With COUT only printing location in memory?

Tags: c++

I am not able to print the actual contents of my list object.  When I use std::cout<< myList; I get a compiler error saying error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}’ and ‘List’)

The program works when I use std::cout<< &myList; but it only prints the location in memory.  Below is my main file.  I am also including the operator overloading function I defined

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "list.h"
#include "loadfile.h"
#include "book.h"

int main( int argc, const char * argv[] ) {
List myList;
load_book_data("test_subset.tsv", myList);
List & myI = myList;
std::cout<<myList;
return 0;
}

// operator overloading, this is from a book.cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Book & b)
{
os<<b.isbn()<<'\t'<<b.title()<<'\t'<<b.author()<<'\t'<<b.year()<<'\t'<<b.rating();
return os;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `operator<<` defined for `List`?

Comment: Where did you tell the computer how to print a `List`?

Comment: To give you something to google, "operator overloading"

Comment: You already have defined `operator<<()` for `Book`, you must do the same for `List`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define operator '<<' for your 'List' composite type:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const List& obj)
{
    std::cout << obj.someListField << std::endl;

    return os;
}
```

Your example works with

```
std::cout<< &myList;
```

just because '&myList' is of pointer type, and the standard has already defined operator '<<' for that, which obviously prints a memory address to stdout.